# Ubuntu servers timing out after changing netplan

Tags: dns, netplan

My goal is simply to set a static IP using Netplan on Ubuntu server 20.04.
My configuration leads to problems, possibly with name servers.

Since I am working on a bare metal machine, I am configuring `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

The original contents of `00-installer-config.yaml` were as follows:

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

I followed all the best advice and adjusted it to

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      addresses: [192.168.0.111/24]
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [96.114.21.40,96.114.14.140,68.87.41.40]
  version: 2
```

I executed `netplan generate`, then `netplan apply`, then rebooted.

I received no complaints from netplan. All the spacing is correct (@ 3 spaces/indent). I used no tabs to space.
It looked like all was well until I tried to update the system or install any new program.
**The Ubuntu servers would not do anything and would timeout**. When I revert to the original yaml file, the Ubuntu servers cooperate again.

I later read that Ubuntu servers not cooperating was due to possibly having done something wrong with the name servers.

Xfinity is my internet provider. I did an NSlookup:

```
nslookup xfinity.com
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   xfinity.com
Address: 96.114.21.40
Name:   xfinity.com
Address: 96.114.14.140
Name:   xfinity.com
Address: 68.87.41.40
```

What am I doing wrong?

1. Is there a "subiquity" somewhere that I need to disable?  (Bare metal machine)
2. Do I need to dispose of `version: 2` at the end of the script?

Answer (score 0):

Those don't seem to be the correct nameservers. By doing nslookup on xfinity.com your are just getting the IP addresses of their web servers.

I don't know the correct nameservers for xfinity, but I would suggest trying googles public DNS servers.

Replace the nameserver section of your netplan with:

```
nameservers:
  addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Comment: totally worked!  Thanks so much!